# What is the most efficient way of virtualize large data?

Tags: angular, virtualization, large-data, virtualscroll, perfect-scrollbar

I have a list of cards that contains charts, images on it. Since the chart data and image requests slowdown my application, I thought to follow a virtualization technique. I'm currently using ngx-perfect-scrollbar and I'm about to use the virtual scrolling feature of it.
But I need to know is there a better and faster way that I can visualize the data without lagging the application?'

Below is the code snippet I'm using the create the cards and a sample image of the interface.

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="{{isMobileDevice ? 'mobile-perfect-scrollbar' : ''}}">
                <div class="wl_tile_container_holder">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of rowData" class="wl_tile_container" (click)="onClickTileView(item)">
                        <app-watchlist-tile [data]="item"
                        [isFullMarket]="isFullMarket"
                        [isDefinedWatchlist]="isDefinedWatchlist"
                        [selectedWatchList]="selectedWatchList"
                        [fullView]="fullView"
                        (menuItemClicked)="onSelectMenuItem($event)">
                        </app-watchlist-tile>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Full virtualization offers the best isolation and security for VMs and simplifies migration and portability as the same guest OS instance can run on virtualized or native hardware